# how to calculate date difference and get the output in days?

Tags: sql, hive, datediff, apache-drill, dbeaver

I am trying to calculate difference between two dates in dbeaver connected to apache drill.

ex:

```
date 1  1/27/2019
date 2  2/01/2019
```

output 1 in terms of days
output 2 in terms of weeks

Comment: Tried converting both to timestamps?

Comment: Did you the link about date-time functions in Drill? You can read it and then easily create all these SQL queries. All your cases are very simple and they are mentioned in the Drill docs and in other SQL docs:
https://drill.apache.org/docs/date-time-functions-and-arithmetic/#date_diff

Comment: I tried timestampdiff but not able to get the output, getting some datatype error "DOUBLE" in dbeaver

Comment: I see the main problem is with the dbeaver

Comment: here is my query  select PO_Received,DateSubmitted,DateReleased
,TIMESTAMPDIFF(week,cast(DateSubmitted as TIMESTAMP),cast(DateReleased as TIMESTAMP)) 
from `cotm.views`.REACTRequests limit 10

Comment: ERROR:  SQL Error: SYSTEM ERROR: AssertionError: todo: implement syntax SPECIAL(Reinterpret(-(CAST(TO_TIMESTAMP(/(CAST($2):DOUBLE, 1000))):TIMESTAMP(0), CAST(TO_TIMESTAMP(/(CAST($1):DOUBLE, 1000))):TIMESTAMP(0))))

Answer (score 1):

Well, have you tried `datediff()`?

```
select datediff(date1, date2) as days_between
       floor(datediff(date1, date2) / 7) as weeks_between
```

Comment: This should be the default answer

Answer (score 1):

> if date is in string format -

```
select datediff(
(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(enddate, dateformat), dateformat)) -
(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(startdate, dateformat), dateformat)));
```

Ex - `hive> select datediff(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2019-01-28', 'yyyy-MM-dd'), 'yyyy-MM-dd'), from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2019-01-27', 'yyyy-MM-dd'), 'yyyy-MM-dd'));`